# .htaccess Allowing only the rest of the pages to view

Tags: php, apache2

Hi? How can I allow only a visitor to view only some part of the page and while my IP(assigned IP) can view all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP (as the tag of your question suggests), try including the following in your page:

```
<? if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1") { ?>

[part of page only you can see here]    

<? } ?>
```

where you replace 127.0.0.1 with your IP.

Comment: Thanks For your reply man. I only need an htaccess.:) But still it works.It can be used.